# Возврат к началу программы C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-6

Гуглил я гуглил, и ненагуглил...
Надо сделать возврат к началу программы из функции Comprasion(), не могу понять как это сделать, вот код:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WriteLine("Введите целое число от 1 до 10.");
        int first_num = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());

        WriteLine("Введите еще одно целое число от 1 до 10.");
        int second_num = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());

        Comprasion(first_num, second_num);
    }

    private static void Comprasion(int a, int b)
    {
        if (0 > a <= 10 && 0 > b <= 10)
        {
            Fun(a, b);
        }
        else;
        {
            WriteLine("Вы ввели неверные числа, проверьте и введите повтоно.");
            // Вот тут должен быть переход к началу
        }
    }

    private static void Fun(int n, int k)
    {
        int x = 100;

        for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
        {
            if ((i % n == 0) && (i % k == 0))
            {
                Write(" FizzBuzz ");
            }
            else if (i % k == 0)
            {
                Write(" Buzz ");
            }
            else if (i % n == 0)
            {
                Write(" Fizz ");
            }
            else
            {
                Write($" {i} ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать.

Comment: что значит «**из** функции»? может, вам банальный цикл нужен?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используй `if` и `break` - пускай функция Comprasion возвращает `bool`, а не `void`, и в зависимости от значения, которое вернет функция используй `break` или `continue`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while(true){

        WriteLine("Введите целое число от 1 до 10.");
        int first_num = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
        WriteLine("Введите еще одно целое число от 1 до 10.");
        int second_num = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());

        if(Comprasion(first_num, second_num) == true)
             break;
        else
             continue;
    } 
}

private static bool Comprasion(int a, int b)
{
    if (0 > a <= 10 && 0 > b <= 10)
    {
       Fun(a, b);
       return true;
    }
    else
    {
       WriteLine("Вы ввели неверные числа, проверьте и введите повтоно.");
       return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: ну и небольшой совет :) называй функции понятными именами - `Fun`, по названию нельзя понять что эта функция делает

Comment: и да, такое же не скомпилируется наверное? `if (0 > a <= 10 && 0 > b <= 10)`

Comment: все отлично компилируется и работает как надо))) благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

Оберните весь код в бесконечный цикл. (`for` или `while`).   В результате, метод `Comprasion` будет возвращать управление в `Main` и программа начинаться с начала

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   for(;;;){
    WriteLine("Введите целое число от 1 до 10.");
    int first_num = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());

    WriteLine("Введите еще одно целое число от 1 до 10.");
    int second_num = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());

    Comprasion(first_num, second_num);
     } 
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Только вот выполнение стало совсем бесконечным, а ведь если if исполняется, то программа после показа результата должна останавливаться наверное.